# How To Pass Different Parameters To web Service Every Time It Is Called With Jmeter

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I am testing web service using Jmeter, web service has several methods which takes some parameters. What I need to do is to pass different parameters every time user (thread) "calls" web service method.
I know, that I can do something like that, if I write Soap Messages in xml files and then to "give" Jmeter path of folder including this xml files, but Jmeter will take randomly those files and there is probability to use the same file twice or more. But I want Jmeter to use every request time different unique Soap Message.
Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSV Data Set Config, prepare csv file containing your parameters.

Set CSV config recycle on EOF to false.
Set CSV config stop thread on EOF to true.
Set CSV config Sharing mode to all threads.

Comment: I have a problem passing several Soap Messages to CSV Data. How can I   use the CSV Dataset to hold XML file names? (Xml files - to store Soap Messages)

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you using Raw Data Source PreProcessor for this sake, and have all requests in single file.